# Filter Courses by Progress in Chamilo LMS

Tags: chamilo-lms

I am new to chamilo lms learning system. I had created my portal on Chamilo and added courses also. Now I want to add filters on course home page from where i can filter courses according to their course progress.Filter like completed button filter will filter all the courses who gets completed and partial completed filter will filter process which are not completed yet.

Is there any way from which i can add a course progress filter on course home page ? Any kind of help either suggestion or technical will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you call courses. You seem to be mixing the notion of course (like the course space that offers a homepage) and of learning paths (that have a progress indicator). It is not clear either whether you want to filter courses or only show the tracking information and whether you want to do that as a teacher or as a student. This all makes it very difficult to answer you, but I'll guess.

The progress in the different learning paths can be seen on the learning paths list page. Chamilo is a relatively procedural language, with still relatively few friendly URLs, so it is very easy to understand where to look for examples in the code.

The tracking of learning paths is shown on the main/lp/lp_controller.php page (for your own progress, in chamilo 1.11.0 and above) and can be seen on the same page if you load the script with the "&action=report&lp_id=x" parameters. That should give you a first idea of where to look for the function calls that get the data you want.

Then showing this information on the course homepage is mostly a question of checking the main/course_home/ folder and see where you want to put it. You might need to modify templates in main/template/default/, but not all pages are supported by templates yet.